# AES ECB using slowaes

Tags: python, encryption, python-2.7, aes

Is it possible to do AES **ECB** encryption using the python classes in slowaes?

The `AESModeOfOperation` supports OFB, CFB & CBC modes.  Is there a way to emulate ECB using one of these modes?

Comment: Note that using ECB mode is not secure for almost all purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to use CBC with an IV value of all zero's (16 bytes valued '00' in hexadecimals).

Only encrypt a single block. If you get more than 16 bytes output then the plain text was padded before encryption; only use the first 16 bytes of output.

Now you've got a single block encrypt. ECB mode is simply a concatenation of single block encrypts. So you take 16 bytes of plain text, encrypt with the above, and let the result be the next 16 bytes of ciphertext.

Of course you may have to [pad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29) your message yourself, but that should not be too difficult.

Comment: Works like a charm, and makes perfect sense once you think about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you don't need to do anything special for ecb.  just divide your message into blocks and encrypt each block using the "raw" aes (ie `AES.encrypt()` in Python).  similarly, to decrypt, call `AES.decrypt()` for each block.

the other modes are more complicated, which is why the code in `AESModeOfOperation` is needed for those.

as others have said, this is not secure.  see the discussion at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29) (in particular, look at the penguin images).

Comment: I don't see any specific case in the source to handle the mode if it does not equal one of the OFB, CFB & CBC modes. Maybe it is possible to set the string to `"ECB"` and be done with it? I'm not a python expert...

Comment: @owlstead by `AES.encrypt()` i mean the encrypt methods on an instance of the AES class (not sure if you saw my edit; you commented only slightly afterwards).

Comment: Yes, I understand, but I was wondering if strings other than the modes given would not default to ECB (including padding and what not). That would make the solution a lot simpler (and as a Java person I don't have a Python dev. environment directly available).

Comment: OK, then your solution is probably the best, mine is taking the long road even if it does directly answer the question.